# can we change status bar or notification bar position programmatically

Tags: java, android, statusbar

I had locked my app to portrait only mode and I handled orientation changes myself, but I realized that in landscape mode the status bar stays the same, and the UI experience would be bad.

Now, that I have developed everything accordingly, the only workaround seems to be for me is to change the status bar position programmatically, since I don't(or actually can't at this point) respect system orientation changes.

Is this possible? To change the status bar position programmatically? Only inside my app and restore once I exit?

Below I have illustrated the desired effect:

first, the app is locked to portrait mode and when I rotate the device the app's views rotate since I parse the raw sensor data and apply the rotation, but in this case the status bar doesn't rotate(since the app is locked to portrait mode, and I only have access to app's views for rotation):
[image]

A pseudocode of how I've done the above is:

```
View views[] = new View[]{view1, view2, view3, view4 ....};
float rotationAngle = parseRawSensorData();//typically accelerometer input
for(View view: views){
    rotateWithAngle(rotationAngle);
}
```

Therefore the views rotate but the status bar is affixed.

what I'd like to do is to be able to rotate the status bar using some code like this:
[image]

i.e. rotate the statusbar according to the sensordata I fetch.

Comment: good question, I was looking for something similar in the past but I gave up unable to find any solutions. Good luck with finding it, I've bountied your question

Comment: @juztcode , thanks a lot, really appreciate it. :-)

Comment: adding some code and images would really help!!

Comment: @kelvin , I've added the relevant code and some illustrations.

Comment: what about just hiding the status bar?

Comment: @kelvin , still notifications can arrive, like sms messages or anything else, then the user would be forced to rotate the device to read it, or quit the app temporarily, this would be a bad experience

Comment: although moving the status bar as I've mentioned should in fact be possible, and there must be some hook to do it, because the system itself does it, it should be programmable at least at a developer's level

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your scenario. However, [link]https://source.android.com/devices/tech/display/rotate-suggestions has reference suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The statusbar is part of the Android system, not part of your application. So there is no way you could control that from your application.

Comment: isn't there some sort of way to tell the sytem from the app to place it somewhere?

Comment: if it can't be controlled from the application, where can it be controlled from?

Comment: The people developing Android can control the status bar.

Comment: @Ridcully , I know native c++ NDK development is really low as in comparison though I'm not very familiar with it. Do you know anything there that could achieve this?

Comment: Even with NDK your app is not allowed to change system stuff like the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotating a status bar, you can just hide it when using your app.

Import:

```
import android.view.WindowManager
```

And write this:

```
getWindow().setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    )
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but, heads up notifications can still popup, this is not good if we just hide the app,and it could also be done in the manifest if we were to hide it.